# A batch file conundrum

Tags: batch-file

I am using Windows XP.Trying to create a batch file that will work from any location in response to an user input.It works fine except for a glitch.If the user inputs

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\desktop\file.txt
```

the following batch works fine:

```
set /p X= your file ?  
set /p =Number: <nul  
Find /v /c "" <%1 %X%> linecount.txt msg %username%<linecount.txt || start linecount.txt 
del linecount.txt.
```

But if we assume that the user is computer saavy and he were to use this path

```
%userprofile%\desktop\file.txt
```

with or without quotes the batch file fails with the message the system cannot find the path!. I am at my wits end.

Comment: what's the value of `%1`? Is it defined? Does it contain spaces?

Comment: @ Stephan yep ! since I intended it to cover all cases spaces in the path is a possibility. Actually that %1 parameter was redundant.I have revised my code,see the answer to my question  below

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
set /p X= your file ?  
set /p =Number: <nul  
call set "X=%X%"
Find /v /c "" <%1 "%X%"> linecount.txt msg %username%<linecount.txt || start linecount.txt 
del linecount.txt.
```

Of course, the name must be given in the correct way:

```
%userprofile%\desktop\file.txt
```

**EDIT**: *Output example in Windows XP added*

```
C:\> ver

Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

C:\> type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal

set /p X= your file ?

echo Before call set: "%X%"
call set "X=%X%"
echo After  call set: "%X%"

C:\> test.bat
 your file ?  %userprofile%\desktop\file.txt
Before call set: "%userprofile%\desktop\file.txt"
After  call set: "C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\desktop\file.txt"

C:\>
```

Comment: see above .BTW does your edit work in your PC. Call set is not available in windows xp.

Comment: see my final code below. It can be moved anywhere in your PC or not moved at all you will still get the answer in the form of a message failing which a notepad open to reveal the answer. Thanks anyway Antonio for the effort you took to reply.

Answer (score 0):

EUREKA ! looks like the problem is solved. The code is given below :

```
 set /p X= your file ?
 for /f "tokens=* " %%Y in (' echo %X% ') do  set file=%%Y
 find /v /c "" < %file%  >lines.txt 
 for /f "tokens=*" %%Z in (lines.txt) Do set number=%%Z
 echo Totally %number%  lines >nol.txt
 del lines.txt
 msg %username%  < nol.txt || start "" nol.txt
 del nol.txt
```